# Alternative LAF to quaqua

Tags: java, swing, macos, look-and-feel, quaqua

Since installing the new version of quaqua I have been having weird problems like text not displaying over my intro splash screen and the default java icon showing up on dialogs instead of mine.  I was wondering if anyone knew an alternative to quaqua I could try for Mac LAF.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for this too. But I could not find sth. useful/equivalent. The only very nice one is not production ready:
http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2009/10/01/sea-glass-look-and-feel/

Here is a nice list of other L&F:
http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/component/content/article/37-core-java/65-20-free-look-and-feel-libraries-for-java-swings.html

Here is one more:
http://developer.k-int.com/maven2/kunststoff/kunststoff/

Another (nice one?) could be nimbus which is included in the sun JDK:
sun.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel

or use the old crossplattform L&F:
UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName()

Answer (score 1):

Everything that I know is here : [javootoo](http://www.javootoo.com/).SkinF has a theme which looks like MacOS but not in all aspects(but it is stable, from what I remember).